# how do you use algolia search in a WebForm

Tags: search, webforms, algolia

When using Angolia Search  standard form search, you have the 'form within a form' problem.
Is there an example that does not assume its MVC but the webform technology?

Comment: Hello,

Do you have an example that illustrates your issue ?
let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one workaround that I know of, and it involves toggling the default ASP.NET form off and on. Initially, I came across this when trying to integrate PayPal with ASP.NET Web Forms and came up against the inevitable single form problem.

Here is the link to the [original code](http://jerschneid.blogspot.com/2007/03/hide-form-tag-but-leave-content.html) for this, and this is a personal [blog post](http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/08/Solution-to-ASPNET-Form-PayPal-Problem.aspx) on integrating it with PayPal. You should be able to use these guides as a basis for integrating Algolia Search.